# Sort numbers with colons

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have a list of Bible verses, times, or some other strings with numbers and colons. I would like those sorted into this:

```
1:5
2:1
2:8
2:14
11:36
```

How would I sort those numbers?

I assume I have to parse the string, separate on colon, and then sort. What I tried gives me things like this:

```
1:5
11:36
2:1
2:14
2:8
```

Comment: Two small suggestion: when you give an example express all inputs as Ruby objects. Here that would be `["1:5", "11:36", "2:1", "2:14", "2:8"]`. It's not unusual to see questions down-voted when inputs are not valid Ruby objects. Secondly, it's helpful to attach a variable to each of those objects: `arr = ["1:5", "11:36", "2:1", "2:14", "2:8"]`. That way, we can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them.

Comment: Expressing inputs as I suggested has the side-benefit of allowing readers to cut-and-paste when they are preparing answers.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for the suggestion. You're absolutely right. :)

Comment: @ryanpitts1 If you think so, you should edit your question and follow the suggestions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable#sort_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by)

```
input = %w|1:5 11:36 2:1 2:14 2:8|
input.sort_by { |e| e.split(':').map(&:to_i) }
#⇒ ["1:5", "2:1", "2:8", "2:14", "11:36"]
```

`map(&:to_i)` part is needed to make integers out of strings, because `11 > 2` but `"11" < "2"`.

Answer (score 6):

```
arr = %w| 1:5 11:36 2:1 2:14 2:8 |
  #=> ["1:5", "11:36", "2:1", "2:14", "2:8"]

arr.sort_by { |s| Gem::Version.new(s.tr(':', '.')) }
  #=> ["1:5", "2:1", "2:8", "2:14", "11:36"]
```

See [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by), [String#tr](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-tr) and [Gem::Version::new](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Version.html#method-c-new). The latter is part of the standard Ruby library.