# Sort numbers separated by colons using R

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

I have the same question as here but using R:

[Sort numbers with colons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53915892/sort-numbers-with-colons)

I have a data frame A with a column like this one:

```
1:5
11:36
2:1
2:14
2:8
```

I'd like to sort A based on that column, in this way:

```
1:5
2:1
2:8
2:14
11:36
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You may want to take a look at `help("order")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `separate` the data into different columns, `arrange` the data by all columns and combine them again.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate(V1, into = c("A", "B"), sep = ":", convert = TRUE) %>%
  arrange_all() %>%
  unite(A, A, B, sep = ":")

#      A
#1   1:5
#2   2:1
#3   2:8
#4  2:14
#5 11:36
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("1:5", "11:36", "2:1", "2:14", "2:8")), 
row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

**1) gtools** `mixedsort` and `mixedorder` in gtools can do that.  We show how to do it for a vector `v` and an entire data frame `DF` which may have additional columns that are to be moved along with the `v` column.  (The test data is defined reproducibly in the Note at the end.  If the v column in DF were factor rather than character then use as.character(DF$v) in place of DF$v).

```
library(gtools)

mixedsort(v)
## [1] "1:5"   "2:1"   "2:8"   "2:14"  "11:36"

DF[mixedorder(DF$v), ]
##       v x
## 1   1:5 1
## 3   2:1 3
## 5   2:8 5
## 4  2:14 4
## 2 11:36 2
```

**2) Base R**  This alternative is slightly longer but only uses base R.  It gives the same answers as (1).  The comment about factors in (1) applies here too.

```
o <- do.call("order", read.table(text = v, sep = ":"))
v[o]

o <- do.call("order", read.table(text = DF$v, sep = ":"))
DF[o, ]
```

### Note

Test data used

```
v <- c("1:5", "11:36", "2:1", "2:14", "2:8")
DF <- data.frame(v, x = seq_along(v), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `order` + `gsub`, i.e.,

```
r <- v[order(as.numeric(gsub(":.*","",v)),
             as.numeric(gsub(".*:","",v)))]
```

such that

```
> r
[1] "1:5"   "2:1"   "2:8"   "2:14"  "11:36"
```